# Why can't we store final long variable in byte variable directly

Tags: java, casting, primitive

```
    final int a =100;
    byte b = a;  //will compile successfully.

    final long l =100;
    byte c = l ; // giving type cast error
```

Any specific reason behind this?

Comment: if you set `a` to some velue exceeding byte range, say 1000, it also would require casting. If you remove `final`, it also will require casting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, why int to byte auto cast is possible... Basically (according java rules about auto casting primitives) it shouldn't.

Main rule in auto casting with primitives: "we don't wont lose information". So it is possible to widening types only.So int will be casted to long (no loosing information) while long cannot be auto casted to int (long can hold bigger numbers than maximal integer value). This rule should be exactly passed to byte... but you find that int to byte auto cast is possible...

Comment: The reason the first conversion works is because the bytecode generated for `final int a = 100` is `bipush` which pushes a byte on the stack as an int and `final` is used to make `a` a *compile-time constant*

Comment: @TheLostMind The reason that the first conversion works is that the JLS defined it to work, and the JLS didn't define it for long constants assigned to a byte, even if the value is in range for a byte.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - We are saying the same thing in different ways. Of course this has to be there in the JLS

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation -

***A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.***
Here they didn't mentioned about the **long** so it has to be explicitly typecast by the developer.
**reference** - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 0):

That's really awkward behaviour. By the way, if you increase int variable value to 1000, for example, the code will give the same cast error. It is a kind of inconsistency as it seems that for types which use one word for storing their values are checked for value limits whereas "big" types like `long` are not. However, it's a bad idea to use such casts implicitly.